# ManyToMany relation in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have such domains:

> ParameterValue
>
> public class ParameterValue extends StatefulEntity {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.SequenceGenerator.PARAMETER_VALUE,
>         strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
> @SequenceGenerator(
>         sequenceName = Constants.Sequence.PARAMETER_VALUE_SEQ,
>         name = Constants.SequenceGenerator.PARAMETER_VALUE,
>         allocationSize = 1
> )
> private Long id;
>
> @Column
> private BigDecimal rangeStart;
>
> @Column
> private BigDecimal rangeEnd;
>
> @Column
> private LocalDateTime timeStart;
>
> @Column
> private LocalDateTime timeEnd;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmDictCode;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmDictFieldId;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmDictFieldCode;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmValue;
>
> @Column
> private String textValue;
>
> @Column
> private BigDecimal numberValue;
>
> @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
>         cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
> private Parameter parameter;
>
> @JsonIgnore
> @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parameterValues")
> private List<RateValue> rateValues = new ArrayList<>(); }
> ```

parameter:

> public class Parameter extends StatefulEntity {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.SequenceGenerator.PARAMETER,
>         strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
> @SequenceGenerator(
>         sequenceName = Constants.Sequence.PARAMETER_SEQ,
>         name = Constants.SequenceGenerator.PARAMETER,
>         allocationSize = 1
> )
> private Long id;
>
> @Column
> private String code;
>
> @Column
> private String description;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmDictId;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmDictFieldId;
>
> @Column
> private String mdmDictFieldCode;
>
> @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false,
>         cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
> private ParameterType parameterType;
>
> @Column
> private Boolean nullable;
>
> @JsonIgnore
> @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parameter")
> private List<ParameterValue> parameterValues = new ArrayList<>();
>
> @JsonIgnore
> @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parameters")
> private List<Rate> rates = new ArrayList<>(); }
> ```

Rate_value

> ```
> public class RateValue extends StatefulEntity{
>
>     @Id
>     @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.SequenceGenerator.RATE_VALUE,
>                     strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
>     @SequenceGenerator(
>             sequenceName = Constants.Sequence.RATE_VALUE_SEQ,
>             name = Constants.SequenceGenerator.RATE_VALUE,
>             allocationSize = 1
>     )
>     private Long id;
>
>     @JsonIgnore
>     @JoinColumn(name = "rate_id")
>     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false,
>             cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
>     private Rate rate;
>
>     @Column
>     private String currencyCode;
>
>     @Column
>     @NotNull
>     private BigDecimal interestValue;
>
>     @Column
>     private Boolean isInterest = false;
>
>     @Column
>     private BigDecimal minValue;
>
>     @Column
>     private BigDecimal maxValue;
>
>     @Column
>     private Boolean isDefaultValue = false;
>
>     @NotNull
>     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>     @JoinColumn(name = "rate_rate_pack_link_id")
>     private RateRatePackLink rateRatePackLink;
>
>     // ссылка на параметры
>     @ManyToMany(
>             fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
>             cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH}
>     )
>     @JoinTable(name = Constants.Table.RATE_PARAMETER_VALUE,
>             schema = Schema.RATES,
>             joinColumns = {
>                     @JoinColumn(name = Constants.Column.RATE_VALUE_ID,
>                             referencedColumnName = Constants.Column.ID)
>             },
>             inverseJoinColumns = {
>                     @JoinColumn(name = Constants.Column.PARAMETER_VALUE_ID,
>                             referencedColumnName = Constants.Column.ID)
>             }
>     )
>     private List<ParameterValue> parameterValues = new ArrayList<>();
>
>     @Column
>     @NotNull
>     private String branchValue;
>
> }
> ```

Status

> @Data @Audited @Entity @Table(
>           name = Constants.Table.STATUS,
>           schema = Schema.RATES,
>           uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
>                   name = Constants.UniqueConstraint.STATUS_CODE, columnNames = Constants.Column.CODE
>           ) ) @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) public class Status extends GenericObject {
>
> ```
> @Id
> @GeneratedValue(generator = Constants.SequenceGenerator.STATUS,
>                 strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
> @SequenceGenerator(
>         sequenceName = Sequence.STATUS_SEQ,
>         name = Constants.SequenceGenerator.STATUS,
>         allocationSize = 1
> )
> private Long id;
>
> @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
> protected String code;
>
> @Column
> protected String description; }
> ```

I want to select all RateValues without
rateValue.parameterValue.parameter.status = "active", if RateValues dont have activeparameters query should return RateValues without parameters.

```
  @Query(value = "FROM RateValue r "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.status "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH r.parameterValues v "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH v.parameter p "
            + "WHERE v.parameter.status.code= 'ACTIVE'",
```

Currently this query returns me all RateValues which had parameterValues with parameter.status = ACTIVE.

But I need all RateValues and parameterValues of this rateValue which had parameter status ACTIVE

Comment: Your tables don't matter. What matters is your entities, because JPQL works with entities, not tables. Post the code of your entities, explain what the query should do and what it does instead.

Comment: I just edited with full code

Comment: There is no status property anywhere. And you still haven't explained precisely what you expect this query to do and what it does instead.

Comment: When I so the query  HQL automatically connect it to the status Entity and make realtion.  There are no problems with getting status of the entiites. I exaplained my problem, add status Entitiy and edited my question) Thank you

Comment: Its very importnat for me, I`m new at this one and now had complex query on hql, losting

Comment: As I explained as it should to be?

Comment: I still don't see any status field anywhere, and still don't understand what this query returns and what it should return instead.

Comment: This query returns me RateValues which had parameterValues with parameter status ACTIVE.  But I need All RateValues and the parameterValues with parameter status Active, instead just RateValues with parameter status ACTIVE

Comment: Yes, HQL automaticaly make connection from my DB, which had status on Parameter. It works and dont make some problems with this one

Comment: Can I directly write you a message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734679/hibernate-manytomany-select

Comment: I found little bit similiar question and change it on my situation, the link above, can you check it