# Hibernate ManyToMany select

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Context: I have two tables `Secret_Agent` and `Secret_Mission`. Both have a @ManyToMany relationship with each other since many secret agents can be given to perform the same secret mission and the same secret agent can be given many secret missions.

**Table SECRET_AGENT**

| SecretAgentId | SecrentAgentName |
| --- | --- |

**Table SECRET_MISSION**

| SecretMissionId | SecrentMissionName | SecretMissionStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |

**JOIN Table SECRET_AGENT_MISSION**

| SecretAgentId | SecretMissionId |
| --- | --- |

Java Code:

```
class Secret_Agent { 
. . .

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinTable(name ="SECRET_AGENT_MISSION", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name =
   "SecretAgentId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
@JoinColumn(name = "SecretMissionId") } 
private List <Secret_Mission> missions; 
. . . 
}

class Secret_Mission { 
. . .

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "missions") 
private List <Secret_Agent> agents;
. . . 
}
```

problem: I`m trying to get all Agents and agents mission with status = Active. But query below retrieve me just Agents who had missions with status Active.

```
 @Query(FROM FROM Secret_Agent sa "
            + "LEFT JOIN FETCH sa.missions sm"
            + "WHERE sm.status = "ACTIVE" ")
```

There mission status can be Archive or Active.
I need just All Secret Agents with missions which had status ACTIVE or just SecretAgent entity with empty mission.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this problem by mapping your association twice in the following way with `@Where` annotation.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "agents") 
@Where(clause = "status = 'ACTIVE'")
private List activeMissions

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "agents")
private List missions
```

Complete explanation can be found here https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-filter-entities-mapped-association/

Comment: If I will map it twice and run those query: is that will return m all Agents and missions which had active status

Comment: or it should return me just agents with active missions

Comment: you should change your query then to `LEFT JOIN FETCH sa.activeMissions` and as `@ManyToMany` has `FetchType.Lazy` by default, mission collection will not be initialized.